# How can I resolve Code will be never executed error

Tags: c

I am making a program that reads input from a user then check the validity,
but for the while statement in the validateInput function I am getting an warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int ValidateUser(char *);
int ValidateInput(int);
FILE *database;

struct{
  int year;
  int unit;
  float gpa;
  char semester;
  char grade;
  char name[40];
}student;

int ValidateInput(int x)
{
    while (x != 1 || x != 2 || x != 3) // code that causing a warning
    return x;
}

int ValidateUser(char *input)
{
    int result;
    result = strcmp(input, student.name);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (result != 0)
        {
            printf("The Username you entered does not exit. Please enter correct name.");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() 
{

  printf("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\t|\t\t\t\t Santa Monica College\t\t\t\t\t |\n");
  printf("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
  printf("\t\tWelcome to Santa Monica Student Record System.\n\n");
  printf("Please Enter Your Option\n");
  printf("\t1.View GPA/GRADE\n");
  printf("\t2.Add New GPA\n");
  printf("\t3.Modify Information\n");
    
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    char UserName[40];
    
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
        printf("The GPA of %s is %f , %c ", student.name, student.gpa, student.grade);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
    }
    else
    {
        ValidateInput(choice);
    }
 
  
  return 0;
}
```

The ide was suggesting to add parentheses around x-values in the argument of while statement in the ValidateUser  to make it silence

I've done some research on this warning and I found that the condition I made is not true so that's why I am getting it, but I am not quite sure what the problem is.

Can someone help me out with this???

Comment: It is unlikely that the `while` is pointed to by the message. Please double check. I suspect that the message refers to the (empty) line after the while loop, which indeed can never be reached because the while loop is predictably always an endless loop (once entered...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I mistyped the question. It was for the while statement in ValidateInput() function could you explain on it too???

Comment: You already have answers for the question you asked here. If you have another one create a separate question post for that. Otherwise it would be considered a non-appreciated "moving target" question. Making a [mre] would have prevented all that awkwardness... It pays to reproducably only show the code you actually want to ask about. Also generally try according to [ask].

Comment: Oh okay. I’m new to here so figuring out. Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

In `validateUser()`, your program will reach the

> ```
>         while (result != 0)
> ```

only in the event that the `while` condition is initially true, so if it reaches the loop, it will enter it.  The body of the loop does not modify `result`, so if it enters the loop, it will loop indefinitely.

Ultimately, if the first branch of the `if` / `else` is taken, then the function `return`s from within that branch, and if the second branch is taken then control never exits that branch.  Either way, the

> ```
>     return 1;
> ```

at the end of that function cannot be reached.  Of course, that's just a symptom.  The infinite loop is the main problem.

It's unclear what behavior you actually want here, but what would be most in keeping with the name of the function would be for it to *only* evaluate whether the specified user name is valid, returning a result that conveys either "yes" or "no".  There is no particular reason why such a function would need to loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

You put `while (result != 0)` inside function `ValidateUser(char *input)` and never put a way to get out of the loop, resulting in the return value below it never running.

To fix this, you would need to add a `break;` somewhere in the loop to indicate that you are ready to leave the current loop, or make `result = 0;`

The difference between the two is that `break;` will indicate that the rest of the loop doesn't need to run and will jump out of the loop, or use `result=0;` to run the rest of the code in the loop and then jump out of it

Comment: You explained the `else` of the `if`. I propose to explain why the `then` also cannot allow the last return to be executed, even if it seems obvious to you and me.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the insight, will do for now on

Comment: You helpfully explained how to make a way out of `else`. But the `return` at the end of the function is only unreachable because the "then" path of the `if` also does not allow to reach the second return.  Which means that your explanation only explains why the empty line after the while cannot be reached, but not really why the second `return` cannot be reached.